# Azure pg ERROR: must be superuser to create superusers

Tags: postgresql, azure

pgAdmin 4 connected to Azure already as a "**Server admin login name**", attempt to replicate my working pg DB at Azure, when applying this generated script received:

> "ERROR:  must be superuser to create superusers"

```
-- Role: postgres
-- DROP ROLE postgres;

CREATE ROLE postgres WITH
  LOGIN
  SUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  CREATEDB
  CREATEROLE
  REPLICATION
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md5x1...';
```

How to make myself a superuser?

Comment: You cannot create superuser, refer this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users). Since this service is a managed PaaS service, only Microsoft is part of the super user role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create superuser, as we are given only an admin user when we create the PG server resource. See official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users).